# How to use window object in angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to use scrollTo() function of window object. Directly by accessing window.scrollTo(0,0), i can achieve this functionality. When i googled about using window in angular, people are creating a provider like below one:

```
import {InjectionToken, FactoryProvider} from '@angular/core';

export const WINDOW = new InjectionToken<Window>('window');

const windowProvider: FactoryProvider = {
  provide: WINDOW,
  useFactory: () => window,
};

export const WINDOW_PROVIDERS = [windowProvider];
```

Inside service using like the below code:

```
import {Injectable, Inject} from '@angular/core';
import {WINDOW} from './window.provider';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class WindowService {
  constructor(@Inject(WINDOW) public window: Window) {}
}
```

In module

```
    {provide: WINDOW_PROVIDERS, useValue: window},
```

Everything works with the above code, but while running test cases i m getting the below error. Almost half of the application test cases are failing with below error

```
NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken window!
```

Default Test case for window.service

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { WindowService } from './window.service';

describe('WindowService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => TestBed.configureTestingModule({}));

  it('should be created', () => {
    const service: WindowService = TestBed.get(WindowService);
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

How to fix this??

Comment: in module `providers: [windowProvider]`

Comment: I assume your WINDOW_PROVIDERS is valid injection token so use it in your service as `@Inject(WINDOW_PROVIDERS) public window: Window`

Comment: I have added in app module providers arrays.. i have given in question also

Comment: @user2900572 Please share the test file

Comment: I have added it..its default test case.. All other test cases r also failing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the following `configureTestingModule`:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [WINDOW_PROVIDERS, WindowService]
});
```

Comment: U r correct i forgot to add in providers array.. thanks Oron :)